# CRM 2011 LookUp QuickFind OnChange event

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

In Dynamics CRM 2011 on a `lookup` you have an auto-complete(QuickFind) feature.

`OnChange` event will fire up if you will select some value manual. But, if you will select value from `QuickFind` it doesn't.

How to trigger my function on lookup auto-complete?

Comment: looks like a rollup issue (I mean an error that happens on a specific rollup) did you test this behavior in different environments as well?

Comment: Nope. We have only CRM 2011 UR15 environments. And they are the same. Thanks for response. I will try to find some other environments to test this.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was in wrong connections roles that wasn't supported by my entities. For some reason CRM doesn't handle situation in which user select wrong role. At this point of time value of this lookup still equal to old value because system are waitinging for user input to validate values.

Because of this there no `OnChange` event - values wasn't changed.